# How can I modify an init script on CentOS 7?

Tags: systemd, init-script, debugging

I have a script in `/etc/init.d` that I'm trying to add `echo` statements to...but all of my changes seem to be ignored.

I'm guessing because the script itself is not actually run but that `systemd` is doing something behind the scenes to continue running the old version of the script.  Is there a way to "load" these changes?

Comment: Don't guess - find out. What distro are you using?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/117549

Comment: Centos 7.2.  I updated the question

Comment: Does a `.service` file _also_ exist for your service, or just the sysv-style script?

Comment: Answerers should not have to find the information that this is `gogs` buried down in the comments to an answer.  _This information should be in the question._  And answerers might also enjoy http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307321/5132 .

Comment: This does not have anything to do with gogs.  I'm just trying to troubleshoot a systemd service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's not a way for `systemd` to load the changes you made to files in `/etc/init.d` because `systemd` is largely ignoring the files anyway. See the gory details at [How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/117549).

Consider asking a different question about the specific problem you are attempting to solve by editing /etc/init.d files.

I could guess that perhaps you are looking for `ExecStartPre=` or `ExecStartPost=`. Read `man systemd.service` for other directives that you can use in your systemd service unit files.

Comment: This was the answer.  To troubleshoot, I just copied the script outside of /etc/init.d, modified it, and ran it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right tracks. You will need to reload systemd's context using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

It was a lot easier in the SysV days :)

Comment: No, the old init scripts are largely ignored as answer linked in Jeff's comment explains.  Reloading any part of systemd won't make changes appear to be active.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work: [vagrant@gitserver ~]$ sudo head /etc/init.d/gogs
#!/bin/sh

echo "ZZ"
[vagrant@gitserver ~]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[vagrant@gitserver ~]$ sudo systemctl start gogs
[vagrant@gitserver ~]$